# Button to turn off all layers in ToC at once?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, table-of-contents, visibility

I have created a map that has a Table of Content that i use to turn on and off desired layers. Is there a way to create a 'Clear' button that will untoggle the selected layers? I have a clear button that clears other selections but I am stuck. I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.17.

```
    var myLayerList = new LayerList({
        map: map,
        showLegend: false,
        layers: [
        waterFeature,
        volleyball,
        trashcan,
        tennis,
        table,
        soccerField,
        shadeStructure,
        restroom,
        ramada,
        pool,
        playground,
        pathway,
        parkSign,
        parking,
        park,
        light,
        horseShoe,
        grill,
        drinkingFountain,
        dogPark,
        dogBag,
        discGolf,
        communityGarden,
        bikeRack,
        benches,
        battingCages,
        basketball,
        ballfield]
    }, "layerList");
    myLayerList.startup();




       query("#clearQuery").on('click', function (evt) {
           //reset the definition expression
           selectedLayer.setDefinitionExpression('1=1');
           map.graphics.clear();



       });
```

Comment: I've tried using 'if' statements but im still new to coding and wasn't sure on how to go about it. I was hope there was an example on the developers.arcgis.com website but i could not find anything.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you've tried, and what happens when you try it (any errors)

Answer (score 1):

This link provides some good sources to get you started:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html

Dynamically create a list of all the loaded layers referencing this code snippet

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_dynamiclayerlist.html

You may then tie the updateLayerVisibilty() method from a button click event to loop through the layer list and turn each off.